# Javaで利用可能なメモリサイズのデフォルト値は？

Tags: java

Javaでは-Xms256mのように利用可能なメモリを指定できますが、指定しない場合のデフォルトサイズ
はどのようになりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java SE 8のドキュメントを直訳すると以下のようです。

-Xms

- Java SE 5.0以前：プラットフォームごとの適切なサイズ
- Java SE 5.0 ～ Java7：物理メモリの1/64より大きい適切なサイズ
- Java8以降：Old世代とYoung世代に割り当てられたサイズの合計

-Xmx

- Java SE 5.0以前：64MB
- Java SE 5.0 ～ Java7：物理メモリの1/4より小さい適切なサイズだが、最大でも1GBまで
- Java8以降：言及はありませんが、Metaspace領域の特性から考えると可能な限り

Java8ではヒープメモリのPermanent領域が消えて、
代わりにネイティブメモリにMetaspace領域が追加されました。
これに合わせてメモリ関連のオプション・ツールが変更されています。

○公式ドキュメント（一部情報が古いので、解説記事と合わせてご確認ください。）
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

○解説記事
http://equj65.net/tech/java8hotspot/
http://www.slideshare.net/YaSuenag/metaspace

Comment: Daisuke Shimamoto さんの回答では2GBのようですが、上記では最大1GBになっていますね。。。うーん。。。手元では4GBですね。。。

Comment: @Tsuneo Yoshioka
Java 8では[メモリの管理が結構変わった](http://equj65.net/tech/java8hotspot/)ようです。ドキュメントは更新漏れでしょうか…

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka 自分は 64bit 環境でした。64bit の時代に 1GB のデフォルトは小さすぎる気がしますね…。ドキュメントの更新漏れ可能性大な気が…

Answer (score 7):

下みたいに Java コマンドで確認できるみたいです。

```
% java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | grep -i heapsize
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520        {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 134217728       {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2147483648      {product}
```

Comment: Bladean Mericle さんのコメントでは最大で1GBのようですが、上記では2GBになっていますね。。。うーん。。。